# Guice - Binding classes from resource producer

Tags: cdi, guice, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

My purpose is to produce EntityManager and Logger SFL4J implementations for my cucumber guice unit tests.

I've created the following resource producer

```
public class MockResourcesWeb {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MockResourcesWeb.class);

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        try {
            entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("h2-test").createEntityManager();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn("Failed to initialize persistence unit", e);
        }
    }

    @Produces
    public EntityManager getEntityManager(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        return entityManager;
    }

    @Produces
    public Logger produceLog(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        return LoggerFactory.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
    }

}
```

Now I guess I should bind those classes using my implementation of **AbstractModule** so:
public class ServiceModule extends AbstractModule {
@Override
protected void configure() {
bind( EntityManager.class ).to(?);
// ... (further bindings)
}
}

I have no idea how to realize this. I've also tried by expliciting it:

```
bind( EntityManager.class ).to(Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("h2-test").createEntityManager());
```

But it still fails to compile.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My purpose is to produce EntityManager and Logger SFL4J
> implementations for my cucumber guice unit tests.

To have instance of `EntityManager` and `SFL4J` using guice injection

you can use [`cucumber-guice`](https://javadoc.io/doc/info.cukes/cucumber-guice/1.2.5/index.html) as below

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-guice</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Then in a `Global` class

```
import com.google.inject.Singleton;
import io.cucumber.guice.ScenarioScoped;

// Scenario scoped it is used to show Guice
// what will be the shared classes/variables and instantiate them only in here
@ScenarioScoped
//@Singleton
public class Global {
 
   public EntityManager  entityManager = new EntityManager();
}
```

Create a `BasePage` class and pass `Global` in constructor

```
//import classes   
public class BasePage {

    protected Global global;

    public BasePage(Global global) {
        this.global = global;
    }
}
```

Now in your stepdefinitions ( unit tests or other cucumber tests)

```
  import com.google.inject.Inject;
  //import other classes as necessary

public class StepDefs extends BasePage {
    
         public static EntityManager entityMgr; 
    
        @Inject
        public StepDefs(Global global) {
            super(global);
            StepDefs.entityMgr = global.entityManager
        }
     //use entityMgr as needed

     //note that a new instance of entityMgr will be created for each scenario in feature file`
     // to create an instance that will last for all tests use @singleton in Global class . ex : for sfl4j
  }
```